# Update mysql table value in another table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have two tables. I want to update some value in another table

```
Table 1

id | value    | prefix
------------------------
1  | red      | 0
2  | blue     | 0
3  | green    | 1
4  | yellow   | 1
5  | pink     | 1
6  | black    | 1
```

I want output like this

```
Table 2

id | value   | prefix
------------------------
1  | green   | 1
2  | yellow  | 1
3  | pink    | 1
4  | black   | 1
```

and table 2 values already exists. I want output like this

```
 id   | value   | prefix
 ------------------------
  1   | book    | 0 
  2   | pen     | 0
  3   | green   | 1
  4   | yellow  | 1
  5   | pink    | 1
  6   | black   | 1
```

Comment: Your question is fuzzy!

Comment: Where does "book" and "pen" come from?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry,ask something not related to this question,it's night in China and are you just got up? It seems that you are always online! LOL

Comment: LOL, @lucumt :)

Comment: first select values from table 1 where prefix =1  and then insert it into table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to select data from `table1` then insert into `table2`
Try this:

```
insert into table2 select value, prefix from table1 where table2.prefix = 1
```

Nevertheless, I don't think your approach is efficient

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL JOIN statements. There are various JOINs, must you learn all kinds of them so that you have a better hang on what kind of a JOIN you want to use.
It's well explained at: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp